# How to filter some xml tags in llm streaming output?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, large-language-model

I use python3.
If llm output is streaming, it will return one token at a time.
My full output is a xml, but llm streaming out maybe split a whole tag.
How to filter some xml tags in llm streaming output?

For example:

```
outputs = [
    "<case>",
    "<id",
    "1</id>",
    "<reaso",
    "n>This case involves a",
    " wrongful death claim alleging failure",
    " to diagnose lung cancer. However, the court granted summary judgment to the ",
    "defendant doctor because the evidence did not show a sufficient reduction in chance of survival under the state statute.</re"
    "ason>123",
    "<is_sati",
    "sfy>False</is_satisfy>",
    "</case>"
]
```

one item in this list is a llm streaming output at a time.
If i want have a blacklist, discard or delete 1 and <is_satisfy>False</is_satisfy>, delete tag and it`s content, how can i do?

I use a deque(maxlen=4)

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious get all the output, turn it into a string, then use standard XML modules on it?